# openSSL error in Scrapy while creating project

Tags: python, openssl, scrapy, web-crawler

I have just installed scrapy and all the things along with it as per from scrapy tutorial site.
When I create project using Scrapy with such command

> scrapy startproject [projectname]

so it gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\python\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)

File "c:\python\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals

File "C:\Python\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
 cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)

File "c:\python\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

File "c:\python\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\version.py", line 6, in <module>    
    import OpenSSL

ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

After that even I tried to install openSSl manually using pip 
but it saying that package is already installed

Help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can satisfy the missing dependency by doing the following:

1. You need to install OpenSSL binaries on your system. Get binaries
   from here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries
2. Then you need to install pyOpenSSL, from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.13

Comment: although I am able to use it by canopy but not able to use it by 
default python installed at C:/python27
I have installed scrapy at both places 
Is there anything I did wrong...

Comment: Canopy includes OpenSSL by default, probably it's bundled with the installer. But for the default python you need to install OpenSSL dependencies manually.